# Could I rely that PrimaryGroupToken is immutable?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk, activedirectorymembership

Based on my investigtaion there are 2 things:

1. `PrimaryGroupId` from User side
2. `PrimaryGroupToken` operational attribute from Group side

User references to group `PrimaryGroupToken` operational attribute using field `PrimaryGroupId`

There are 2 ways to to get `PrimaryGroupToken`

1. Based on primaryGroupToken operation attribute

```
val entry = ldapConnectionPool.getEntry(groupDn, "*", "primaryGroupToken") 
val primaryGroupToken = entry.getAttributeValue("PrimaryGroupToken")
```

2. Based on `objectSid` suffix

```
val entry = ldapConnectionPool.getEntry(groupDn)
val domainSidBytes = entry.getAttributeValueBytes("objectSid")
val domainSidString = LdapUtils.convertBinarySidToString(domainSidBytes)
val primaryGroupToken = domainSidString.substringAfterLast("-")
```

I haven't found any direct way how I can get group entry by user primaryGroupId so I started to think about application level cache. But I expected that primaryGroupToken is a constant group identifier but this page confuses me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-primarygrouptoken

[image]

As you can see it is mentioned that this attribute could be updated. Based on my exeriments - I was not able to achieve it. Could you please clarify if this attribute is immutable or not ?

Answer (score 1):

In reality, the `primaryGroupToken` never changes. That said, it's not the best way to find a group since it's not indexed.

One way I've used to bind directly to a group from the user's `primaryGroupId` is to construct the SID of the group. The last portion of the SID is called the RID (Relative Identifier). It's a number that is incremented for each new object on the domain. Everything up to the last hyphen identifies your domain and is the same for every object on the domain.

You can construct the SID of the group by taking the user's SID, take everything up to the last hyphen, then add on the value of `primaryGroupId`.

For example, if we have a user with:

```
objectSid: 'S-1-5-21-1004336348-1177238915-682003330-12345'
primaryGroupId: 12346
```

Then the SID of the group is:

```
S-1-5-21-1004336348-1177238915-682003330-12346
```

Active Directory lets you [bind directly to an object by the SID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/binding-to-an-object-using-a-sid) using this format:

```
LDAP://example.com/<SID=S-1-5-21-1004336348-1177238915-682003330-12346>
```

By default, the `primaryGroupId` will be `513` for all users, which is always the `Domain Users` group.

Comment: Sorry but what is the relation of `bind` by sid and getting entry by `primaryGroupToken` ? For me `bind` is authentification operation

P.S. I  am specifically interested in unboundId ldap sdk solution.

Comment: Binding to an entry is the same as "getting" an entry. So in this case, you're getting the entry using the SID rather than by the `primaryGroupToken`.

Comment: Could you provide UnboundId request for that stuff ? I suppose it should single line code

Comment: I'm not a Java developer and I've never used UnboundID, but based on the documentation, you can probably get the group with `ldapConnectionPool.getEntry("<SID=S-1-5-21-1004336348-1177238915-682003330-12346>")` (using the SID you constructed).